# No Gradle Tasks appearing under projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have an eclipse project that is running inside of the VM.  It uses gradle and has the eclipse buildship plugin installed.  The build.gradle file is present but for some reason it won't show any gradle tasks for the project like it normally does.  It also has a red x by the project names and gives me the error that "import *** cannot be resolved" for basic things like ImmutableLists even though the import statements are all present at the top of the files.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?  [Picture showing the red x's as well as the options I have selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8ijN.png)

Comment: Look in the Problems view for more details about the errors

Comment: What even is the name of the view that you are showing?